# Filter rows where column value ends with a set of patterns

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I have a data set as follows

```
File_name     Folder
ord.cpp        1
rod.ibo        1
ppol.h         2
lko.cpp        3
rto.cp         3
tax.mo         2
t_po..lo.cpp   4
```

I need to subset this data set so that only rows where File_name ends with ".cpp" or ".h" is present in the data set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `grepl` for a base R option:

```
df_subset <- df[grepl("\\.(?:cpp|h)$", df$File_name), ]
df_subset

     File_name Folder
1      ord.cpp      1
3       ppol.h      2
4      lko.cpp      3
7 t_po..lo.cpp      4
```

### Demo

Comment: `subset(df,grepl("\\.(?:cpp|h)$",File_name))` just n case

Answer (score 2):

A `dplyr` and `stringr` solution:

```
df %>%
 filter(str_detect(File_name, ".cpp|.h"))

     File_name Folder
1      ord.cpp      1
2       ppol.h      2
3      lko.cpp      3
4 t_po..lo.cpp      4
```

Or with just `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
 filter(grepl(".cpp|.h", File_name))

     File_name Folder
1      ord.cpp      1
2       ppol.h      2
3      lko.cpp      3
4 t_po..lo.cpp      4
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
# Looking for a string eding with .cpp or .h
df[endsWith(df$File_name,(".cpp"))|endsWith(df$File_name,(".h")),]
```

Output:

```
     File_name Folder
1      ord.cpp      1
3       ppol.h      2
4      lko.cpp      3
7 t_po..lo.cpp      4
```

Comment: This is not correct as it will also select values like `ord.mcpp` or even `ppol.mhjh` etc which is not correct

Comment: @Onyambu: I have updated my answer. Could you please give me your feedback?

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `file_ext` function from `tools` package to get file extensions of the file and then use it to subset data frame.

```
library(tools)
df[file_ext(df$File_name) %in% c("cpp", "h"), ]

#     File_name Folder
#1      ord.cpp      1
#3       ppol.h      2
#4      lko.cpp      3
#7 t_po..lo.cpp      4
```